# Library "keyboard" randomly choosing upper or lower letters

Tags: python

So today i was trying to make something and i ran into a problem. The problem was that when i try to print lower letters or upper letters they just randomly print. sometimes when i press a upper key like "D" it just randomly prints lower d "d" or upper d "D"

I was trying to write a program that detects if a key is pressed.

```
import keyboard
import time
def pressed_key(key):
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
            time.sleep(0.08)
            print(key)
while True:
 pressed_key('D')
 pressed_key('d')
```

Comment: I think `is_pressed()` is case-insensitive. So when you press the key, either call will detect it. Since they're running at different times, it's random which one will happen to run while you have the key pressed.

Comment: 'd' and 'D' are the same key. Therefore, which call to `pressed_key()` prints the key is determined by timing, which has a random element in it.

Comment: If you want to know if they're pressing uppercase D, use `pressed_key('shift+d')`

Comment: And if you want to detect only lowercase, use `keyboard.is_pressed('d') and not keyboard.is_pressed('shift')`

Comment: I tried it but now it just prints lower d 'd', i think that it doesn't even recognize upper d 'D'.

Comment: @Barmar *If you want to know if they're pressing uppercase D, use `pressed_key('shift+d')`* - will this work for enabled Caps lock too?

Comment: I don't know, try it and see.